# HTML: Material Design Lite change the color of the text that the user enters into an input field

Tags: html, css, material-design

For the application I am creating I have a black background for this particular page and when the user types an input into the box the text they type is black and therefore invisible.

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="Username"/>
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" style="color:#b272a9;" for="Username">Username</label>
    </div>

</body>
```

How would I change the input text color in MDL?

Answer (score 1):

Please remove `style="color:#b272a9;"`

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here i what you do, I have 'emulated' your conditions, all looks black initially.

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/MJgRLQ

What I have done is

```
input{
background:black;
color:silver !important;
border:1px white solid !important;
}
```

Also, as a general rule, when working with CMS platforms, sometimes the !important rule is the only way out of a mess:-)

Comment: That works, but MDL is what's causing the problem. [Look here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ggYyNr) as you can see, when we include MDL it makes the text field invisible and does not change the text color.

Comment: AHA:-)
Add this then:
color:silver !important;
  border:1px white solid !important;

Comment: Most strange - Most CMS's would interpret any tag based styles to have greater priority than that specified in classes the tag might inherit. The !Important works, but really shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @ David P
From my experience, it really is often the last resort and way with CMS and these kinds of frameworks. Now I don'tknow about MDL, but usually those framework inline styles are not directly computed, they are parsed afterwards and do not qualify as real inline styles. I know, it sounds odd and I consider angular etc horrible practice. To me, it's clogging up the markup and sep of concerns is out the window, hell, js inline styles at least I see some benefits:-)

Answer (score 0):

Just set the  tag's color to whatever color you want the text to be

```
<input type="text" style="color:white">
```